# Is requests in IIS httppipeline processed serially?

Tags: iis, iis-7, webserver, iis-7.5, httprequest

Based on iis architecture, request from client hitting IIS will pass through httppipeline, specifically through each httpmodule and finally reaches respective httphandlers and then to worker process. Is this happening serially, one after the other?

Say if 10,000 requests hits the webserver concurrently in a sec, is each request get processed one by one? If the webserver has multi-core CPU and high memory capacity, does this helps IIS to handle the requests simultaneously?

Is there any webserver capable to handle requests in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

I just replied to this guys question - very similar, and the answer is the same:

[IIS and HTTP pipelining, processing requests in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299489/iis-and-http-pipelining-processing-requests-in-parallel)

Comment: +1 that make sense, it means that ideally the request are processed in serial, but we can configure IIS in such a way that it created multiple worker process (or ramp-up as needed) to behave like parallel processing.

Comment: i read something similar here http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-multicore-scaling-on-numa-hardware